# Event control in flex as3 (order of events)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have a flex application, the display of this application is build with many containers.
I have a FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE on each of the displayObjects.

What do I want to accomplish?
I want to handle the event only on the top level where it occurred, for instance, if I have a grid and the update occurred in a label somewhere inside, I want to handle the event only on the Grid.

is there a way to accomplish that?

just to emphasize, I don't have any knowledge of the display objects at compile time, only at runtime, the display is being built dynamically to I can't just write the code on the grid, I have to check somehow if the event occurred in a higher level.

I would love some help with this issue, even if it's not code but concept of how to handle this unique issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered stopPropagation()/stopImmediatePropagation() on the event, once you handle that event.

Example: 
Since your button is in canvas. Your event handler method in canvas would look like this,

```
function handleEvent(e:FlexEvent):void {
 trace("In Canvas's handler");
 //do your events...
 e.stopPropagation(); //This stops from propagating e to its parent containers, which is an HBOX. The container can be anything at runtime, it doesnt affect the propagation.

}
```

Try the same example in your other containers too.

Some examples here,

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/events/Event.html#stopPropagation%28%29

Comment: I'm ware of these, how can they help me here?

I'll give an example, I have a button, it's contained within a canvas and this canvas is in an HBOX (again, I don't have this knowledge in compile time, only in runtime)

once the event is fired, it will fire on the button and on the Canvas but not on the HBox, I want to handle this event only once, on the Canvas.

Comment: Edited my answer, the problem is just to stop the event propagation.

Comment: the parents might be relying on child's updateComplete event - this might break something... gotta check Flex component instantiation life cycle to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the `event.target` and ignore if it is not what you're looking for. Or even better: listen for events on top level components and ignore if `target` and `currentTarget` doesn't match.

```
if(event.target != event.currentTarget) 
    return;
```

If you can't do this either, check the parents: if parent is your application or the container that holds the top level items, it is a top level item. Based on the structure of your component, it can be anything like

```
if(event.target.parent == this)
//or
if(event.target.parent == this.theContainer_thatHolds_topLevelItems)
//or 
if(event.target.parent is Application)
//or 
if(event.target.parent is CustomContainerClassName)
```